# SIGABRT Error When Attempting Multiple Annotations on MKMapView

Tags: ios, annotations, mkmapview, sigabrt

I've been working with MKMapView and am placing Annotation Pins on the map. I'm working towards placing 30 pins in the map for 30 different locations and made sure to run the iPhone SDK after adding each additional location. Then, out of nowhere, it started crashing and giving me the dreaded 'SIGABRT'. AG!!

I know that it could possibly be a slight mistake in my syntax but since I've just been copying and pasting code that previously worked, I'm at a loss. I'm considering using MKCoordinateRegionMake to make everything more concise (I read that this could be an option) BUT I've already entered something like 10 stores so it would require a lot of time to switch it over, which I don't want to do if this is a quick fix.

I proceeded to take out all but one coordinate and it worked. Then I added one more back and it worked, etc. For some reason, it worked a bunch of the times, but sometimes it would lock up and crash. I thought it was just specific locations that were a problem but it never seemed to be a problem with the syntax of any location in particular. So now I'm at a loss for what is causing it.

I'm thinking it may be an issue of allocating and releasing that I'm not doing right? I've attempted to "release" certain allocated space during the code but the problem persisted. I also attempted to do it without releasing allocated space during the code, same problem.

Here's the code I'm working with (all the code worked at times, so I've set up title, subtitle and coordinate in the MillersLocations file correctly):

MapViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Miller's Neighborhood Market #56
    MKCoordinateRegion store56;
    store56.center.latitude = 36.8605679;
    store56.center.longitude = -76.2866713;
    store56.span.latitudeDelta = 0.1;
    store56.span.longitudeDelta = 0.1;
    [mapView setRegion:store56 animated:YES];

    MillersLocations *ann56 = [[MillersLocations alloc]init];
    ann56.title = @"Store #56";
    ann56.subtitle = @"Come check us out!";
    ann56.coordinate = store56.center;
    [mapView addAnnotation:ann56];
    [MillersLocations release];
    //Not sure if release should be on this syntax


    //Miller's Neighborhood Market #66
    MKCoordinateRegion store66;
    store66.center.latitude = 37.0942970;
    store66.center.longitude = -76.4584890;
    store66.span.latitudeDelta = 0.1;
    store66.span.longitudeDelta = 0.1;
    [mapView setRegion:store66 animated:YES]; 

    MillersLocations *ann66 = [[MillersLocations alloc]init];
    ann66.title = @"Store #66";
    ann66.subtitle = @"Come check us out!";
    ann66.coordinate = store66.center;
    [mapView addAnnotation:ann66];
    [MillersLocations release];
    //Not sure if release should be on this syntax

    //Miller's Neighborhood Market #21
    MKCoordinateRegion store21;
    store21.center.latitude = 37.0385289;
    store21.center.longitude = -76.4004810;
    store21.span.latitudeDelta = 0.1;
    store21.span.longitudeDelta = 0.1;
    [mapView setRegion:store21 animated:YES];    

    MillersLocations *ann21 = [[MillersLocations alloc]init];
    ann21.title = @"Store #21";
    ann21.subtitle = @"Come check us out!";
    ann21.coordinate = store21.center;
    [mapView addAnnotation:ann21];
    [MillersLocations release];
    //Not sure if release should be on this syntax


    //Miller's Neighborhood Market #67
    MKCoordinateRegion store67;
    store67.center.latitude = 37.6823690;
    store67.center.longitude = -77.5898330;
    store67.span.latitudeDelta = 0.1;
    store67.span.longitudeDelta = 0.1;
    [mapView setRegion:store67 animated:YES];

    MillersLocations *ann67 = [[MillersLocations alloc]init];
    ann67.title = @"Store 67";
    ann67.subtitle = @"Come check us out";
    ann67.coordinate = store67.center;
    [mapView addAnnotation:ann67];
    [MillersLocations release];
    //Not sure if release should be on this syntax

    //Miller's Neighborhood Market #49
    MKCoordinateRegion store49;
    store49.center.latitude = 36.8550990;
    store49.center.longitude = -76.1355950;
    store49.span.latitudeDelta = 0.1;
    store49.span.latitudeDelta = 0.1;
    [mapView setRegion:store49 animated:YES];

    MillersLocations *ann49 = [[MillersLocations alloc]init];
    ann49.title = @"Store 49";
    ann49.subtitle = @"Come check us out";
    ann49.coordinate = store49.center;
    [mapView addAnnotation:ann49];
    [MillersLocations release];
    //Not sure if release should be on this syntax

    //Miller's Neighborhood Market #82
    MKCoordinateRegion store82;
    store82.center.latitude = 36.7848840;
    store82.center.longitude = -76.1587459;
    store82.span.latitudeDelta = 0.1;
    store82.span.latitudeDelta = 0.1;
    [mapView setRegion:store82 animated:YES];

    MillersLocations *ann82 = [[MillersLocations alloc]init];
    ann82.title = @"Store 82";
    ann82.subtitle = @"Come check us out";
    ann82.coordinate = store82.center;
    [mapView addAnnotation:ann82];
    [MillersLocations release];
    //Not sure if release should be on this syntax

    //Miller's Neighborhood Market #40
    MKCoordinateRegion store40;
    store40.center.latitude = 37.1236680;
    store40.center.longitude = -76.5093960;
    store40.span.latitudeDelta = 0.1;
    store40.span.latitudeDelta = 0.1;
    [mapView setRegion:store40 animated:YES];

    MillersLocations *ann40 = [[MillersLocations alloc]init];
    ann40.title = @"Store 40";
    ann40.subtitle = @"Come check us out";
    ann40.coordinate = store40.center;
    [mapView addAnnotation:ann40];
    [MillersLocations release];
    //Not sure if release should be on this syntax

    //Miller's Neighborhood Market #55
    MKCoordinateRegion store55;
    store55.center.latitude = 36.7704630;
    store55.center.longitude = -76.6058140;
    store55.span.latitudeDelta = 0.1;
    store55.span.latitudeDelta = 0.1;
    [mapView setRegion:store55 animated:YES];

    MillersLocations *ann55 = [[MillersLocations alloc]init];
    ann55.title = @"Store 55";
    ann55.subtitle = @"Come check us out";
    ann55.coordinate = store55.center;
    [mapView addAnnotation:ann55];
    [MillersLocations release];
    //Not sure if release should be on this syntax

    //Miller's Neighborhood Market #58
    MKCoordinateRegion store58;
    store58.center.latitude = 36.7818390;
    store58.center.longitude = -76.0479090;
    store58.span.latitudeDelta = 0.1;
    store58.span.latitudeDelta = 0.1;
    [mapView setRegion:store58 animated:YES];

    MillersLocations *ann58 = [[MillersLocations alloc]init];
    ann58.title = @"Store 58";
    ann58.subtitle = @"Come check us out";
    ann58.coordinate = store58.center;
    [mapView addAnnotation:ann58];
    [MillersLocations release];
    //Not sure if release should be on this syntax

    //Miller's Neighborhood Market #57
    MKCoordinateRegion store57;
    store57.center.latitude = 36.8216160;
    store57.center.longitude = -76.4246680;
    store57.span.latitudeDelta = 0.1;
    store57.span.latitudeDelta = 0.1;
    [mapView setRegion:store57 animated:YES];

    MillersLocations *ann57 = [[MillersLocations alloc]init];
    ann57.title = @"Store 57";
    ann57.subtitle = @"Come check us out";
    ann57.coordinate = store57.center;
    [mapView addAnnotation:ann57];
    [MillersLocations release];
    //Not sure if release should be on this syntax

    //Miller's Neighborhood Market #90
    MKCoordinateRegion store90;
    store90.center.latitude = 38.1330690;
    store90.center.longitude = -77.5124230;
    store90.span.latitudeDelta = 0.1;
    store90.span.latitudeDelta = 0.1;
    [mapView setRegion:store90 animated:YES];

    MillersLocations *ann90 = [[MillersLocations alloc]init];
    ann90.title = @"Store 90";
    ann90.subtitle = @"Come check us out";
    ann90.coordinate = store90.center;
    [mapView addAnnotation:ann90];
    [MillersLocations release];
    //Not sure if release should be on this syntax

    //56,66,21,67,49,90,82,40,55,58,57

}
```

The error (Thread 1: Program received signal "SIGABRT".) always happens on the line:

[mapView setRegion:store57 animated:YES];

OR on store90 as well. There's other stores it's happened on too but always on that line. No rhyme or reason that I've determined.

Thanks to anyone that can help! Apologize if I'm a little long-winded, I just wanted to make sure I included any information you'd need to help.

**EDIT**

It worked once I properly synthesized the MKMapView Outlet that I created and then got of the code to release it ("[mapView release];"). I'm assuming MapViews release themselves which would have been the cause of the error.

It worked fine and then I went to add another annotation and it crashed again. When I delete the new annotation it works, so there's a problem when I add more. AG. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely reason for the SIGABRT is that the region for store49 is invalid resulting in an `NSInvalidArgumentException` and the SIGABRT.

For store49 (and all the stores after that), the `longitudeDelta` is not being set.
Only the `latitudeDelta` is being set (twice).

Fix the duplicate `latitudeDelta` settings to `longitudeDelta`.

Another problem is this:

```
[MillersLocations release];
```

This attempts to call `release` on the `MillersLocation` class--not the instance of that class you are creating.  All those lines should be changed to something like:

```
[ann56 release];
```

Also, you don't need to create a region every time to set up an annotation.  For example, you can just do this:

```
MillersLocations *ann56 = [[MillersLocations alloc]init];
ann56.title = @"Store #56";
ann56.subtitle = @"Come check us out!";
ann56.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(36.8605679, -76.2866713);
[mapView addAnnotation:ann56];
[ann56 release];
```

After adding all the annotations, then you can create a region that encloses all the annotations (if that's what you want) or just shows the last annotation and then call `setRegion` once at the end.

Also, you may want to store the stores in a plist and loop through the plist to create the annotations instead of creating them separately in code.

Finally, you should not remove the `[mapView release];` (from `dealloc`) even if it is an IBOutlet.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. I can't believe I overlooked that syntax error with latitudeDelta problem. Such a big help, really appreciate it.

Comment: Also (for anyone who is reading this post for help), you have to add and import the CoreLocations Framework to use CLLocationCoordinate2DMake.